How can I expand Keplr wallet extension?

I use this Keplr wallet for developing.
Whenever touch other position of the screen, this disappears, so it's very troublesome.
How can I expand Keplr wallet extension?

How about pop out mode?
Keplr extension pop up
You'll easily pop out the extension to see without other effects of operation.

I tried, and any other ways?
